# Парсим данные в тэге h3

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Имеется сайт со следующей разметкой:

```
<div class="info"><h3>Текст бла бла</h3> ХИТ!</div>
```

Мне нужно спарсить то что находится в блоке `info` в тэге **h3**
Вот как код моего приложения, но он парсит все что в блоке info

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.21vek.by").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements popTovAll = doc.select("div.info");

            for (int i = 0; i < popTovAll.size(); i++) {
                Element temp = popTovAll.get(i);
                list.add(temp.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив

}
```

Comment: пробовали так `Element temp = popTovAll.get(i); Element temp2 = temp.select('h3'); list.add(temp2.text());`

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev спасибо. работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ответ из комментариев.*

Попробуйте так

```
Element temp = popTovAll.get(i); 
Element temp2 = temp.select('h3'); 
list.add(temp2.text());
```